# Why is Minecraft crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to play Minecraft on my Samsung Chromebook. I got crouton on it and the launcher loads fine, but then I get this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/j/.minecraft/versions/1.11.2/1.11.2-natives-876969899415/liblwjgl64.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/j/.minecraft/versions/1.11.2/1.11.2-natives-876969899415/liblwjgl.so: /home/j/.minecraft/versions/1.11.2/1.11.2-natives-876969899415/liblwjgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at bes.I(SourceFile:2777)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:39)
```

Comment: Is this Pocket Edition?

Comment: This is the full PC version. I downloaded the jar from minecraft.net

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason I thought a Chromebook was a tablet. Nevermind then haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace is suggesting that the file liblwjgl.so ( lightweight java game library ) was compiled to work on a x86 processor not an ARM one. Windows and MacOS basically only run on x86 ( Intel, AMD ) so they probably don't have a an ARM compatiable version of minecraft for PC.

Pocket edition might work as I believe you can now run APK packages on chromebooks and it would have been compiled for an ARM processor anyway ( most mobile devices use ARM processors ). I'm not sure what the controls will be like though...

I had a quick look and this [article](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5494.0) might be able to help you if your really dead set on getting the full version running on your chromebook. But dive in at your own risk! Highlights below:

**halpme**

> I've figured out that I need to break open
>   lwjgl-platform-(version)-natives-linux.jar and replace four files:
>   liblwjgl.so, libopenal.so, and their 64 bit counterparts.

**abcdef**

> Someone ported lwjgl to the raspberry pi (which has an ARM processor).
>   You will need to do something very similar because I think you need
>   opengl es 3.0 support too

**halpme**

> I managed to get it to run. Performance is horrendous, but a higher
>   end Chromebook with 3d acceleration support will get the job done.
>   Here's what you have to do.
>
> 1) Install the Oracle JVM. Instructions here:
>   http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
>   2) Download the minecraft launcher and run it once, allowing it to
>   update and then crash. 3) Install libegl1-mesa. Run the command "sudo
>   apt-get install libegl1-mesa" in a terminal. 4) Download and compile
>   LWJGL for the ARM platform. Instructions are found here:
>   http://rogerallen.github.io/jetson/2014/07/31/minecraft-on-jetson-tk1/
>   5) Patch Minecraft with the libraries that result from the compile.
>   What you need to do is this:
>   --- 1) Find the working directory for Minecraft. This is typically ~/.minecraft
>   --- 2) Navigate to the "versions" folder. Make a copy of the version folder you want to patch and rename it "x.x.xarm" (x.x.x being the
>   version number)
>   --- 3) Open up the copied folder and change the jar and json files inside to the same name.
>   --- 4) Open up the json file and append "arm" after the version number for every instance of an LWJGL library you find inside (disregarding
>   nightly builds)
>   --- 5) Navigate to ~/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl and there will be a folder for each library inside. In each of those folders
>   you'll find a folder marked with a version number. Append "arm" to the
>   end of each.
>   --- 6) Replace the libraries inside those folders with your new libraries. When you reach "lwjgl_platform", you need to break open the
>   .jar file and delete every library except for "liblwjgl.so". Replace
>   that with your new ARM compiled version.
>   --- 7) Make sure that everywhere you see a version number (typically 2.9.1) you append "arm" to the end. This is mostly so that the minecraft launcher has no idea what the files are and doesn't attempt
>   to update them. If you patched the json file correctly, it'll still
>   run.
>   --- 8) Start the game! I might make a shell script soon that does all this for you if the instructions are too complicated.

Comment: I thought java was the only thing Minecraft needed to run and it supported ARM... I'll just try a different build. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As chromebooks might have different specs than normal PCs, this might be the error:

```
 (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
```

Comment: ...and fix might be trying to install 64bit Java, as it probably has problems running on 32bit..